# how to create dynamic array in codeigniter php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I really need help on this.
I have an array that takes data from my input radio buttons. But the problem is these input buttons may not follow the exact numbers because of my where clause in the select statement.

```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Question/resultdisplay">

<?php foreach($questions as $row) {
    ?>

    <?php $ans_array = array($row->correct, $row->wrong, $row->wrong1, $row->wrong2);
    shuffle($ans_array);
    ?>
<p><?=$row->quiz_question?></p>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>" required/><?=$ans_array[0]?><br/>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"/><?=$ans_array[1]?><br/>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"/><?=$ans_array[2]?><br/>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->id?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"/><?=$ans_array[3]?><br/>


<?php
}
?>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Finish"/>
</form>


public function resultdisplay()
{

  $this->data['checks'] = array(
 'ques1' => $this->input->post('quizid1'),
 'ques2' => $this->input->post('quizid2'),
 'ques3'=> $this->input->post('quizid3'),
 'ques4'=> $this->input->post('quizid4'),
 'ques5'=> $this->input->post('quizid5'),
 'ques6'=> $this->input->post('quizid6'),
 'ques7'=> $this->input->post('quizid7'),
 'ques8'=> $this->input->post('quizid8'),
 'ques9'=> $this->input->post('quizid9'),
 'ques10'=> $this->input->post('quizid10'),
 'ques11'=> $this->input->post('quizid11'),
  );

  $this->load->model('quizmodel');
  $this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
  $this->load->view('result_display', $this->data);
 }
```

I want the array to be dynamic. because if the data in the database is more than eleven(11) then the user will not get result for the rest of the quiz.

Comment: loop in the data

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `resultdisplay()` function round to first fetch the questions and then look for an answer to each question...

```
public function resultdisplay()
{
    $this->load->model('quizmodel');
    $this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
    $this->data['checks'] = [];
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= count($this->data['results']); $i++ )   {
        $this->data['checks'][] = $this->input->post('quizid'.$i);
    }
    $this->load->view('result_display', $this->data);
}
```

This will end up with an array (with a numeric index - you can change that by changing `$this->data['checks'][$keyName]=` with whatever you want as `$keyName`).  Any missing answers will have `null`, again you can change this if needed at `:null;`.

Comment: I get this error code  Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: I've removed the `isset()` code and just set it directly.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please consider marking it as answered.